# How can I plot a Lennard Jones Potential like this one with gnuplot?

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I'm beginning to use gnuplot, and I'm trying to plot a LJ potential like this one I have, but just with the 12-6 one.
Also I would like to show on the plot the values of sigma and epsillon used.

sigma = 2.6

epsillon = 5

This is how I would like to look like:

[image]

This is the code I made.

```
set xlabel "Distance r_0 ({\305})" 
set ylabel "Energy E (J/mol)
f(r,sigma,epsilon)=4*epsilon*((sigma/r)**12-(sigma/r)**6)  
plot[2:5.2] [-6:12] f(x,2.6,5) title '12-6 LJ'
```

I'd appreciate any help and advice. I am a self-taught student, and apologise if this question is trivial.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Here is a first attempt:

```
f(r,sigma,epsilon)=4*epsilon*((sigma/r)**12-(sigma/r)**6)

sigma=2.6
epsilon=5

set arrow 1 from first 3,0 to first 3, f(3,sigma,epsilon)
set arrow 2 from first 3,0 to first 2.8, f(2.8,sigma,epsilon)
set label 1 "(r_0, {/Symbol e}_0)" at first 3,0 center offset 0,1

set xlabel "Distance r_0 ({\305})" 
set ylabel "Energy E (J/mol)

set xr [2:5.2]
set yr [-6:12]

set key reverse Left at 4,5

plot for [epsi= epsilon-1:epsilon+1:1 ] f(x,sigma,epsi) title sprintf("12-6 LJ {/Symbol s}=%.1f {/Symbol e}=%.1f",sigma,epsi)

set term pngcairo enhanced 
set out "LJ.png"
replot
```

and here is the result:

[image]